# Understanding a particular proof that a Hermitian matrix has an orthonormal basis whose diagonal contains its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, quantum-mechanics

From pg. 36 of Shankar's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*:

> [image]

Here in red (which confuses me) Shankar seems to be appealing to this proof:

**Lemma: If an n-dimensional square operator has an eigenpair, it necessarily has (n) (not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues.**

*Lemma proof sketch:*

1. Suppose $Ω |V\rangle = ω |V\rangle$ (that is assume $Ω$ has at least one eigenpair $|V\rangle$ and $ω$).
2. Then $\det(Ω - ω I) = 0$, else $Ω - ω I)$ would be invertible, leading to a contradiction.
3. But $\det(Ω - ω I)$ can be expanded to a characteristic polynomial, which when set to 0 contains $n$ roots (a fundamental fact from complex analysis).
4. Hence these $n$ (not necessarily distinct) roots must be eigenvalues via (2).

**NOTE:** The full details of this proof, as actually presented in the Shankar's book, can be found [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/trash/png/5.png).  I suspect there's a chance I've misunderstood it, though I don't see how?

**Problem 1:** I am having trouble understanding this argument, since it seems to me this might merely imply that $Ω$ doesn't have any eigenpairs. That is, (4) may simply be false, since this would only imply that (1) is false. Or put differently: the above proof merely seems to me to suggest the claim that "*If* (1) is true, then (4) must be true", but (1) might not be true!

The proof continues with more confusion for me:

> [image]

**Problem 2:** Why must the first column of the basis be $[ω_1, 0, …, 0]^T$? This seems equivalent to saying that

$$
\Omega | \omega_1 \rangle = \omega_1 |1\rangle
$$

but I don't see why this must be so.  Perhaps it has something to do with the following two facts, but I don't quite see the connection?

1. $\Omega | ω_1 ⟩ = ω_1 | ω_1 ⟩$
2. $‖ω_1 | ω_1 ⟩‖ = |ω_1| ‖ |ω_1 ⟩‖ = |ω_1| 1 = |ω_1|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** What is left implicit here is that the condition $\det(\Omega - \omega I) = 0$ is in fact equivalent to $\omega$ being an eigenvalue of $\Omega$. Indeed, we have
\begin{aligned}
\det(\Omega - \omega I) = 0 &\iff \Omega - \omega I\text{ is not an isomorphism} \\
&\iff \Omega - \omega I \text{ is not injective} \\
&\iff \text{ there is a vector $V$ with }(\Omega - \omega I)V = 0 \\
&\iff \text{ there is a vector $V$ with } \Omega V = \omega V 
\end{aligned}
So it is really true that a complex number $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of $\Omega$ if and only if it is a zero of the characteristic polynomial.

**Problem 2:** The first column being $[\omega_1, 0, \dots, 0]^T$ just means that $\Omega \vert\omega_1\rangle = \omega_1 \vert\omega_1\rangle$. Recall: what does it mean to write a linear transformation as a matrix? It means that for every element $e_i$ of some chosen basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$, you write each $\Omega e_i$ as
\begin{aligned}
\Omega e_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \Omega_{ij} e_j,
\end{aligned}
and the coefficients $\Omega_{ij}$ will be the matrix coefficients appearing in the $i$-the column. In this case, we choose the basis $\{\lvert \omega_1 \rangle, V^1, \dots, V^{n-1}\}$, and we have
\begin{aligned}
\Omega \vert\omega_1\rangle = \omega_1 \vert\omega_1\rangle = \omega_1 \vert\omega_1\rangle + 0 V^1 + \dots + 0 V^{n-1},
\end{aligned}
and thus the matrix coefficients on the first column are $[\omega_1, 0, \dots, 0]$.

Note that there is no mention of a vector $\vert 1 \rangle$.